# Send an parameter to a modal window (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, rest, api, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have this code in `.ts`

```
openFormModal(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PartidoComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.id = id;

    //modalRef.componentInstance.id = id;
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And this code in `component.html`

```
<button (click)="openFormModal(calendario.fixture_id)">Open Modal</button>
```

I can see the modal that comes from another component is always the same because I cannot send the corresponding `id`. Does anyone know how to send the parameter correctly?

Comment: Passing the data to the modal window depends on how your modal service is implemented. Are you using Angular Material for modal dialog or bootstrap?

Comment: I use this component https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.

For me the solution was as follows:
This code was correct:

```
modalRef.componentInstance.id = id;
```

Then I wrote a `console.log` in `ngOnInit` and the value is displayed correctly then I moved the code that does the API query to that section in this way:

```
ngOnInit () {
     console.log (this.id);
     this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe ((params) => {
       this.lpefService.getPartidos (this.id)
       .subscribe ((data: any) => {
         this.partidos = data.api.fixtures;
         console.log (this.parts);
       });
     });
   }
```

[image: modal]

[image: console.log]

I hope it helps you, if anyone knows a better solution than the one, please

Answer (score 3):

Create a component named `child`(to show modal), then in its Html :

```
<ng-template #childmodal let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Create New Item</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group row m-b-15">
                This is a Modal- Id is {{this.itemId}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="hideModal()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

and in its typescript :

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public itemId: number;

  private modalRef: NgbModalRef;
  @ViewChild("childmodal", { static: false }) child: any;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  open(id: number) {
    this.itemId = id;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.child);
    this.modalRef.result.then(result => {}, reason => {});
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.modalRef.close();
  }
}
```

Now , In the parent component to show modal:

Html :

```
<app-child></app-child>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="this.openModal()">
  Open Modal
</button>
```

typescript (in the `openModal` method we generate a random number to send to modal as Id):

```
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false }) childModal: ChildComponent;

  openModal() {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    this.childModal.open(id);
  }
```

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxsbtj)